# Delete a key-value pair from a list of dictionary having field of same name

Tags: python, list, dictionary, typeerror

```
newlist= [{'row': 4, 'col': 4}, {'row': 4, 'col': 5}, {'row': 4, 'col': 6}, {'row': 4, 'col': 7}, {'row': 4, 'col': 8}, {'row': 4, 'col': 9}, {'row': 4, 'col': 10}, {'row': 5, 'col': 4}, {'row': 5, 'col': 5}, {'row': 5, 'col': 6}, {'row': 5, 'col': 7}, {'row': 5, 'col': 8}, {'row': 5, 'col': 9}, {'row': 5, 'col': 10}, {'row': 6, 'col': 4}, {'row': 6, 'col': 5}, {'row': 6, 'col': 6}, {'row': 6, 'col': 7}, {'row': 6, 'col': 8}, {'row': 6, 'col': 9}, {'row': 6, 'col': 10}, {'row': 7, 'col': 4}, {'row': 7, 'col': 5}, {'row': 7, 'col': 6}, {'row': 7, 'col': 7}, {'row': 7, 'col': 8}, {'row': 7, 'col': 9}, {'row': 7, 'col': 10}, {'row': 8, 'col': 11}, {'row': 9, 'col': 11}]
```

I want to delete the key value pair **having row 4,col 5**
how to do that

```
                        for lines in newlist :
                            if lines['row'] == 4and lines['col'] == 5:
                                print("delete")
                                del added['row']['col']
```

trie above code but not worked.it shows an error **TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

The requirement is for below code

```
          row=4
          cols=4
           l=9
            m=11
            added=[]
            while row <= l:
                print("row", row)
                m = 11
                cols= 4
                while cols <= m:
                    print("column",cols)
                    for li in newlist:
                        print("li", li)
                        if li['row'] == row and li['col']!= cols:
                            added.append({
                                'row':row,
                                'col':cols,
                                # 'id':li['id']
                            })
                            print(row, "", cols)
                            print("new")

                        print("lop",added)

                        new_added = [x for x in added if x['row'] != row or x['col'] != cols]


                    cols = cols + 1
                row = row + 1
```

so I require only

```
newlist= [{'row': 4, 'col': 11}, {'row': 5, 'col': 11}, 
{'row':'6','col:'11'} ,{'row':'7','col:'11'}{'row': 8, 'col': 4}, 
{'row': 8, 'col': 5}, {'row': 8, 'col': 6}, {'row': 8, 'col': 7}, 
{'row': 8, 'col': 8}, {'row': 8, 'col': 9}, {'row': 8, 'col': 10}, 
{'row': 9, 'col': 4}, {'row': 9, 'col': 5}, {'row': 9, 'col': 6}, 
{'row': 9, 'col': 7}, {'row': 9, 'col': 8}, {'row': 9, 'col': 9}, 
{'row': 9, 'col': 10}]
```

so I want output as above

```
newlist 3=out [{'row': 4, 'col': 4}, {'row': 4, 'col': 5}, {'row': 4, 'col': 6}, {'row': 4, 'col': 7}, {'row': 4, 'col': 8}, {'row': 4, 'col': 9}, {'row': 4, 'col': 10}, {'row': 4, 'col': 11}, {'row': 5, 'col': 4}, {'row': 5, 'col': 5}, {'row': 5, 'col': 6}, {'row': 5, 'col': 7}, {'row': 5, 'col': 8}, {'row': 5, 'col': 9}, {'row': 5, 'col': 10}, {'row': 5, 'col': 11}, {'row': 6, 'col': 4}, {'row': 6, 'col': 5}, {'row': 6, 'col': 6}, {'row': 6, 'col': 7}, {'row': 6, 'col': 8}, {'row': 6, 'col': 9}, {'row': 6, 'col': 10}, {'row': 6, 'col': 11}, {'row': 7, 'col': 4}, {'row': 7, 'col': 5}, {'row': 7, 'col': 6}, {'row': 7, 'col': 7}, {'row': 7, 'col': 8}, {'row': 7, 'col': 9}, {'row': 7, 'col': 10}, {'row': 7, 'col': 11}, {'row': 8, 'col': 4}, {'row': 8, 'col': 5}, {'row': 8, 'col': 6}, {'row': 8, 'col': 7}, {'row': 8, 'col': 8}, {'row': 8, 'col': 9}, {'row': 8, 'col': 10}, {'row': 8, 'col': 11}, {'row': 9, 'col': 4}, {'row': 9, 'col': 5}, {'row': 9, 'col': 6}, {'row': 9, 'col': 7}, {'row': 9, 'col': 8}, {'row': 9, 'col': 9}, {'row': 9, 'col': 10}, {'row': 9, 'col': 11}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try via list comprehension:

```
checker=[{'row':x,'col':y} for x in {x['row'] for x in newlist} for y in range(4,12)]
#created a list of dict by the given range provided by you
out=[x for x in checker if x not in newlist]
#only get those elements of checker list which are not present in newlist
```

output of out:

```
[{'row': 4, 'col': 11},
 {'row': 5, 'col': 11},
 {'row': 6, 'col': 11},
 {'row': 7, 'col': 11},
 {'row': 8, 'col': 4},
 {'row': 8, 'col': 5},
 {'row': 8, 'col': 6},
 {'row': 8, 'col': 7},
 {'row': 8, 'col': 8},
 {'row': 8, 'col': 9},
 {'row': 8, 'col': 10},
 {'row': 9, 'col': 4},
 {'row': 9, 'col': 5},
 {'row': 9, 'col': 6},
 {'row': 9, 'col': 7},
 {'row': 9, 'col': 8},
 {'row': 9, 'col': 9},
 {'row': 9, 'col': 10}]
```

Comment: I *think* the logic is wrong here.  The OP only wants to delete items that meet the criteria `row=4` and `col=5`, but this excludes the very first entry: `{'row': 4, 'col': 4}`

Comment: You need x != 4 or y != 5 because that is equivalent of `not(x == 4 and y== 5)`

Comment: @Mark added both condition Sir...thanks for the suggestion **:)**

Comment: @AlbinPaul added both conditions sir...thanks for the suggestion **:)**

Comment: @AnuragDabas please check the above code..This requirement is used in above code.But not got correct output

Comment: @Shahal what are you trying to achieve can you explain the logic?

Comment: @AnuragDabas  I want to get a list of dictionaries ,, condition is that it take row from 4 to 9 and cols from 4 to 11.. and i want print those row:col pair that not come in  first newlist mentioned in questn and it give output like 2nd newlist in qstn

Comment: @Shahal then why you are getting only one pair of these `[{'row': 4, 'col': 11}, {'row': 5, 'col': 11}]` row=4 or 5 and why col is 11 because there are col that starts with 4 upto 11?

Comment: @AnuragDabas Because in the first new list  {'row': 4, 'col': 11}, {'row': 5, 'col': 11} this in not present

Comment: @Shahal ok then why `{'row':'6','col:'11'}` and `{'row':'7','col:'11'}` is not present in your expected output because they are also not in newlist?

Comment: @AnuragDabas sorry they are also present in the 2nd newlist

Comment: @Shahal updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: @AnuragDabas it shows output as in newlist 3 ..not expected output

Comment: @Shahal the checker list is your expected output then...print checker variable and you will get your expected output

Answer (score 0):

Use the remove method for lists:

```
for dic in newList:
    if dic['row'] == 4 and dic['col'] == 5:
        newList.remove(dic)
```

Comment: This will fail on input like: `[{'row': 4, 'col': 4}, {'row': 4, 'col': 5},{'row': 4, 'col': 5}]`